# $\mathbb{P}(X_j = j^\alpha) = \mathbb{P}(X_j = -j^\alpha) = 1/2 j^\beta, \mathbb{P}(X_j = 0) = 1 - j^\beta,$ $X_1 + ... + X_n$ converges a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For $\beta>1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_j = j^\alpha) = \mathbb{P}(X_j = -j^\alpha) = 1/2 j^\beta, \mathbb{P}(X_j = 0) = 1 - j^\beta,$ show $X_1 + ... + X_n$ converges almost surely.

It's easy to show that $\mathbb{P}(X_i \neq 0 \text{  i.o.}) = 0$, but I'm not sure how to use this to deduce that  $X_1 + ... + X_n$ converges almost surely. Any help?